# Am I having Kotlin functions return a List correctly?

Tags: android, list, function, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin (coming from Delphi, which is object-oriented Pascal). I just want to ensure I am having functions return `List<>`s correctly:

Making up an absurdly simple example here:

```
    fun firstTenInts(): List<Int> {
        val iList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
        for (i in 1..10)
            iList.add(i)
        return iList
    }
```

So, my thoughts/questions here are:

- Am I correct to use a `MutableList` within the function and simply return it (even though the function's type is `List`)?
- Do I *need* to create a local `MutableList` variable? Do I *need* any local "list" variable? I am used to (again, Delphi) doing something like:

```
    function firstTenInts: TStringList;
    var
      i: integer;
    begin
    result.Clear;
    for i := 1 to 10 do
      result.Add(IntToStr(i));
    end;
```

which requires no "new" local variable. I simply "work" `result` which is very similar to Kotlin's `return` value except that it serves as a local variable of the function's type which can be "worked" throughout the function.

- Is there no way to manipulate a Kotlin function's `return` value other than with another (locally created) variable?
- Finally, I can rest assured that any local variables I create are destroyed when the function ends even though I'm "passing them back" - correct?

P.S. I know this is an absurd way to create a `List` of 10 integers. I am using this only as a framework for the questions/issues I have detailed above. Assume that the returned `List` will be of unknown size.

(Please do not suggest better ways of creating this list of integers; that is not what I am asking about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Am I correct to use a `MutableList` within the function and simply return it (even though the function's type is `List`)?

Generally that's ok. You do such things if you require a list that can be mutated within the function but from outside you do not want it to be easily mutable (which doesn't mean that it isn't mutable; you could still cast it to a mutable list, i.e. `firstTenInts() as MutableList` would work and so you could also mutate it again). 
Whether you need that mutable list in the function or not actually depends on you. For example just calling `listOf(1, 2, 3)` will return you a `List<Int>` immediately, i.e. `fun first3Ints() = listOf(1,2,3)` will immediately return a `List<Int>`.

> - Do I need to create a local MutableList variable? Do I need any local "list" variable? I am used to (again, Delphi) doing something like:

You do not need to, but you can. It's up to you what better suites your needs. This also applies to your local list variable. You do not necessarily need one, even though you will have one nonetheless under the hood. Example:

```
fun first3Ints() = listOf(1, 2, 3)
```

translates to something like the following:

```
fun first3Ints() : List<Int> {
  val result = listOf(1, 2, 3)
  return result
}
```

On smaller functions you at least can spare some variable declarations using direct assignments. You can also use something like `apply`, `also`, `let`, `run` or `with` to overcome `val/var`, e.g. (just simulating... all variants can be implemented easier):

```
fun first3Ints() = arrayListOf().apply {
  add(1) // apply allows calling all methods of the receiver directly.. (receiver = arrayListOf...)
  add(2)
  add(3)
}
fun first2Ints() = arrayListOf().also { // similar to apply, but now there is an 'it' available... you could also name that variable differently, e.g. using .also { result -> result.add(1) }
  it.add(1)
  it.add(2)
}
```

> - Is there no way to manipulate a Kotlin function's `return` value other than with another (locally created) variable?

So this becomes yes (even though .. technically speaking there will be one)... it is possible, but you need to specify on what you basically want to operate, except for the case where you implement an extension function. Then `this` within the extension function actually becomes the object you called the function on.

> - Finally, I can rest assured that any local variables I create are destroyed when the function ends even though I'm "passing them back" - correct?

... yes and no. Yes, you can rest assured that any local variable will be garbage collected when need arises (except you are doing something very special). And there is also the no: you don't know when they will be destroyed. Regarding your returned value it is even more special: you are actually getting only a reference to an object, not the object itself... so somehow you basically get that local variable back. You may want to have a look at JVM / stack and heap and how the objects are referenced and stored...

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot of useful info. I still can't figure out, however, how to do something like `this.add(...)` or `it.add(...)` within a function to add elements to the functions return value (some `MutableList`) rather than needing to create a local variable...

Comment: ok... maybe I jumped too fast into something like `also`, `apply`, etc. You should probably start with a local variable instead... and if you are feeling more comfortable with the language itself, you may also start using something like direct function assignment... for the moment, just assume that basically you are safe, i.e. the variables will be cleaned up for you... so concentrate on what's more readable first ;-)

Comment: to answer your comment a bit better: without a direct function assignment (i.e. `fun x() = listOf(...)`) you need to have some local variable (or at least operate on something that will lead to the type you want to return) in place, e.g. `fun x() : List<..> { return <eitherLocalVariableOr: listOf(...)> }`

Comment: Thanks again. it does seem a strange "feature" to be lacking in a language that is so syntactically powerful, though. I mean there is **so much** in Kotlin that's about less text & here we've got a situation that not only requires more text - but the creation of a local variable that I'm just not used to needing.

Comment: Well.. with `let`, `run`, `with` or `map`/`filter` you can do a lot and may omit local variables in future..

Comment: I'm already using `let`, `with` and `run` in various places in my code. Can you show me how I'd use one of them (or something else) to `add` to a `MutableList` that is the return type of a function within that function? Thanks.

Comment: Example using `also`, that returns a list containing the given value, if it is greater 0 or otherwise an empty list: `fun f(x : Int) : List<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>().also { if (x > 0) it.add(x)}`.. the caller only sees a `List<Int>`, but it actually is a (/the) `MutableList<Int>`..

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193113/discussion-between-free-dorfman-and-roland).

Answer (score 0):

Your return is right and you can use ArrayList instead of mutableListOf and there will be no problem...
but still I didn't understand your main problem but the main topic you were talking about shows that  you want to be sure of using the list as a return and that is right man

Comment: Not a problem, per se. I just want to know if this is the right way of returning a `List` in Kotlin. Also: are you *suggesting* an `ArrayList` instead of the `MutableList`? If so, why.

Comment: I'm not sure but  maybe for memory allocation for *mutable* or *immutable* variable like val and var. for example this is better to use val instead of var in kotlin regarding to this documentaion  https://medium.com/techmacademy/kotlin-101-val-vs-var-behind-the-scenes-65d96c6608bf or  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-variables

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways for creating `ArrayList` of 10 items *(just as an example you given)*. You can find below code snippet such as example :

```
// directly returning array list as Kotlin has functionality to define such kind of function just like macros

fun firstTenInts(): List<Int> = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

// Or by using standard function apply

fun firstTenInts(): List<Int> = ArrayList<Int>().apply {
        for (i in 1..10)
            this.add(i)
    }

// Or by declaring variable of ArrayList

fun firstTenInts(): List<Int> {
    val iList = ArrayList<Int>()
    for (i in 1..10)
        iList.add(i)
    return iList
}

// Or by using standard function with

fun firstTenInts(): List<Int> = with(ArrayList<Int>()) {
    for (i in 1..10)
        this.add(i)
    return@with this
}
```

Above are the various examples defines how you can do differently *(Although sample you provided is also a valid example)*.